# Wordpress site not accessible for external users

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

My WordPress site is not accessible for external users. The only page there is should be published. It's not set to private or anything else. I checked every setting I can think of.

I'm working most of the time in Google Chrome, therefore, my Wordpress account is still logged in and I'm able to see the webpage. But when I go on safari and type in the URL. It will take me to the wp-admin login page. This is strange since the page should be published.

I'm not using an FTP server.

Any ideas?

Comment: it seems you wrote some logic to login before visiting the site, might be possibly a plugin may be enabled and it is redirecting a non-loggedin user

Comment: Deleted a plugin. Sometimes the answer is already there. Thanks for the heads up!